# WinAPI, всплывающие подсказки и UNICODE

Tags: c, winapi, tooltip

Я пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как в `WinAPI` делаются всплывающие подсказки. Общий принцип мне ясен, но есть проблема.

В примере, который я разбираю, всплывающая подсказка реализуется с `ANSI` текстом, а не с `UNICODE`. Я предположил, что для использования `UNICODE` мне будет достаточно использовать специальные `UNICODE` типы и функции.

- `TOOLINFOW` вместо `TOOLINFO`;
- `TTM_ADDTOOLW` вместо `TTM_ADDTOOL`;
- и так далее.

Но по неизвестной мне причине, всплывающая подсказка в режиме `UNICODE` не работает.

Вот мой исходный код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void CreateMyTooltip(HWND);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Tooltip";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName,
                  L"Tooltip",
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                  100,
                  100,
                  200,
                  150,
                  0,
                  0,
                  hInstance,
                  0);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,
                         UINT msg,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            CreateMyTooltip(hwnd);
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateMyTooltip(HWND hwnd)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
    iccex.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    iccex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex);

    HWND hwndTT = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOPMOST,
                                  L"tooltips_class32",//TOOLTIPS_CLASSW,
                                  NULL,
                                  WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  hwnd,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL);

    SetWindowPos(hwndTT,
                 HWND_TOPMOST,
                 0,
                 0,
                 0,
                 0,
                 SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    TOOLINFOW ti;
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFOW);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = hwnd;
    ti.hinst = NULL;
    ti.uId = 0;
    ti.lpszText = L"Кириллица";
    ti.rect.left = rect.left;
    ti.rect.top = rect.top;
    ti.rect.right = rect.right;
    ti.rect.bottom = rect.bottom;

    SendMessageW(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFOW) &ti);
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

**PS:** Я знаю о том, что можно определить макроопределения `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE` и использовать обобщенные макросы, которые будут разворачиваться в нужные версии типов и функций: `SendMessage()` -> `SendMessageA()` / `SendMessageW()`. Но я бы хотел разобраться с кодом, который непосредственно  работает с `UNICODE`, чтобы понимать, как можно смешивать `UNICODE` и `ANSI` вызовы в одной программе, потому что такая потребность возникает довольно часто.

Comment: У меня этот код работает, если заменить `sizeof(TOOLINFOW)` на макрос `TTTOOLINFOW_V1_SIZE`. В причинах не разбирался, но это связано с [версией библиотеки ComCtl32.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/common-control-versions#structure-sizes-for-different-common-control-versions)

Comment: @t3f, большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @t3f, где можно найти подробную информацию по этой проблеме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я добавил сообщение об ошибке в ваш код, а заодно исправил ошибку при инициализации `TOOLINFOW` (и выкинул лишнее):

```
TOOLINFOW ti;
memset(&ti, 0, sizeof(ti));
ti.cbSize = sizeof(ti);
ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
ti.hwnd = hwnd;
ti.lpszText = L"Кириллица";
::CopyRect(&ti.rect, &rect);

LRESULT lr = SendMessageW(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFOW) &ti);
if (!lr) ::MessageBox(NULL, L"TTM_ADDTOOL failed!", L"Tooltip Test", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```

Действительно, код работает только для структур версий 1 и 2. Для версии 3, которая поддерживается начиная с Windows XP, `SendMessage/TTM_ADDTOOL` возвращает ошибку. После разбирательства причина прояснилась.

Когда вы используете `sizeof(TOOLINFOW)` или (что в данном случае то же самое) `TTTOOLINFOW_V3_SIZE`, вы задаете структуру, которая поддерживается библиотекой CommCtl версии 6, которая стала доступной начиная с Windows XP, вместе с `TOOLINFO` версии 3. Однако для подключения этой библиотеки включения хедера недостаточно, ее необходимо указать в манифесте. Без указания этой зависимости в манифесте подключается библиотека контролов версии 5, в которой не поддерживается `TOOLINFO` версии 3, соответственно `TTM_ADDTOOL` не срабатывает.

Подробнее о CommCtl версии 6 и манифесте можно прочитать в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview).

Для того, чтобы включить CommCtl версии 6 в манифест есть два способа:

1. Использовать директиву `#pragma` в коде программы:

`#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")`

2. Либо добавить зависимость в настройках проекта `Linker / Manifest File / Additional Manifest Dependencies` и вставить туда строку

`"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'"`

После добавления библиотеки в манифест ваш пример нормально заработал. Изменился только фон тултипа, потому что в версии 6 он выбирается визуальным стилем.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Я так понимаю, оба решения предполагают использование `MS VC`. А как решить проблему, если используется `MinGW-w64`?

Comment: @MGNeo, я только по VS что-то знаю. Но по идее любой линкер должен уметь прицеплять к exe файл манифеста. Без него ведь не подключить новые контролы, да и уровень выполнения UAC (asInvoker, asAdministrator) тоже оттуда берется. Посмотрите по ссылке что я дал, там примеры .xml манифеста.