# Значение макроса TTTOOLINFOW_V1_SIZE в WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

Используя `WinAPI` и пытаясь реализовать всплывающие подсказки, я столкнулся с неочевидными особенностями создания `UNICODE`-подсказок.

То есть, если я определяю макроопределения `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE`, а затем использую обобщенные макросы структур и функций, которые раскрываются в `UNICODE`-версии оных, то проблем нет.

Так же, если я пытаюсь явно использую `ANSI`-версии структур и функций, то проблем тоже нет.

Однако, если я пытаюсь явно использовать `UNICODE`-версии структур и функций, то всплывающие подсказки не работают.

В результате долгих поисков, мне удалось найти информацию о том, что вместо:

```
TOOLINFOW ti;
ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFOW);
```

Необходимо использовать:

```
TOOLINFOW ti;
ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V1_SIZE;
```

Но подсказки так же работают, если использовать:

```
TOOLINFOW ti;
ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE;
```

И не работают, если использовать:

```
TOOLINFOW ti;
ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V3_SIZE;
```

Эти макросы определены так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я совершенно не понимаю, что делают эти макросы и каковы правила их применения...

Буду очень благодарен за любую информацию по этой проблеме.

Comment: Вы используете WinApi в учебных целях? Просто, сейчас использование голого WinApi для построения пользовательского интерфейса не актуально и есть море фреймворков. Копание в WinAPI оправдано только если вы хотите изобрести свой велосипед-фреймворк.

Comment: Все эти *удобные* и *мощные* фреймворки давно выродились в нечто монструозное, тяжеловесное и нестабильное. Я преимущественно разрабатываю ПО для промышленности, где крайне важна надежность и поддерживаемость. Поэтому в основном используется `C`, `WinAPI` и максимально аскетичные и проверенные временем библиотеки, вроде `libmodbus`.

Comment: Qt,VCL, Windows Forms, WPF существуют многие годы и до сих пор поддерживаются. Для Qt и VCL так на машине клиента вообще ничего ставить не нужно=> можно считать легковесным. Используя готовые фреймворки экономится море времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пошли совершенно не в том направлении. Эти макросы не для пользователя, это чисто служебные макросы, в которые вам совершенно не надо вникать. Впрочем, по порядку.

Во-первых, в качестве небольшого отступления - не стоит самому определять символы `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE`. Они должны определяться в IDE, например в VS открываете свойства проекта и на странице General выбираете "Character Set".

Точно так же не надо прямо выбирать варианты `xxxA` или `xxxW`, нужно всегда использовать имя `xxx`. Только в редких случаях приходится прямо указывать суффикс, и при этом лучше понимать зачем вы это делаете и почему это необходимо.

Теперь по поводу поля `cbSize` в структурах. Программы, как известно, имеют свойство развиваться и изменяться. Появляются новые версии функций, которые принимают новые входные данные, при этом нужно поддерживать совместимость со старыми программами. Вот как раз для обеспечения совместимости и ввели поле `cbSize`. Именно по этому полю функции WinAPI и определяют для какой версии WinAPI построена программа.

Для примера посмотрим определение этой самой структуры `TOOLINFO`:

```
typedef struct tagTOOLINFO{
    UINT      cbSize; 
    UINT      uFlags; 
    HWND      hwnd; 
    UINT_PTR  uId; 
    RECT      rect; 
    HINSTANCE hinst; 
    LPTSTR    lpszText; 
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0300)
    LPARAM lParam;
#endif
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
    void *lpReserved;
#endif
} TOOLINFO, NEAR *PTOOLINFO, *LPTOOLINFO;
```

Видно, что оригинальная структура (V1) заканчивалась на поле `lpszText`. С выходом Internet Explorer 3 добавилось поле `lParam`, это версия 2 структуры. И наконец, с выходом Windows XP в структуру добавили указатель, который, правда, так ни во что и не оформился.

Соответственно, семейство макросов `TTTOOLINFO*_V*_SIZE` вычисляют размер этой структуры версий 1,2,3 в вариантах A и W, всего 6 макросов. Обработчик сообщения `TTM_ADDTOOL` проверяет это значение, чтобы определить, вызван ли он с правильной структурой, и подходит ли текущая версия WinAPI.

Так вот, макросы `TTTOOLINFO*_V*_SIZE` вам не нужны, это внутренние служебные определения. Эти значения используются для проверки версии и корректности структуры, но проверяете ведь не вы, а обработчик `TTM_ADDTOOL`. Вам же нужно просто писать

```
TOOLINFO ti;
ti.cbSize = sizeof(ti);
```

Platform SDK, который вы используете, содержит определения `_WIN32_IE` и `_WIN32_WINNT`, а IDE определит для вашего проекта `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE` (если они необходимы). Соответственно объявление `TOOLINFO ti` сгенерирует правильную структуру, и в `ti.cbSize` будет внесено верное значение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение. Вариант с `ti.cbSize = sizeof(ti);` работать не хочет, если `ti` определен как `TOOLINFOW ti;`. Собственно, именно эта проблема изначально и породила мои поиски. Вот мой вопрос с исходным кодом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926788/winapi-всплывающие-подсказки-и-unicode

Comment: @Максим Глухманюк, так проблема с тем вопросом решилась или нет? Вообще непонятно зачем вам понадобилось смешивать Unicode и Ansi вызовы. Вы этим просто создаете себе лишние проблемы, причем никаких преимуществ не приобретаете. Скорее всего вы этим плюс самостоятельным определением _UNICODE позапутали все, оттого глюки и полезли..

Comment: *Точно так же не надо прямо выбирать варианты xxxA или xxxW, нужно всегда использовать имя xxx.* - нет, следует всегда явно использовать wchar_t и функции `xxxW`, и только в редких случаях варинты с А. Варианты без суффикса по большей части являются макросами, призванными упростить переход на юникод API старых приложений (допустим написанных под Win98), а всем новым следует использовать юникод API по-умолчанию.

Comment: @VTT, не собираюсь спорить. Любой вариант работает, хоть с явным указанием суффикса, хоть с неявным через символ UNICODE. А поскольку выбор того или иного варианта объективно обосновать невозможно, то это был бы спор о вкусах. Делайте как вам больше нравится, ваше право.

Comment: @freim, смешивать `...A` и `...W` функции и структуры можно. Такая необходимость в системном программировании возникает очень часто. Тот вопрос, что я привел через ссылку, так и не решился, и я не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: @Максим Глухманюк, а разве я говорил что нельзя смешивать? Я просто смысла в этом никакого не вижу. Впрочем, не знаю, что вы имеете в виду под системным программированием, может там и есть какой-то смысл. Код ваш выглядит нормально, но вот сравнить ни с чем не могу к сожалению - тултипов у меня полно, но все они в MFC программах. Но если код работает с обобщенными именами, но не работает с *W, то явно где-то смешались A и W (на тему пользы смешивания, ага:).

Comment: @freim, я тоже сначала думал, что где-то эти типы смешались. Все перепроверил, ничего подобного не нашел. Судя по тестам, проблема связана с неверным заполнением `ti.cbSize`, почему-то `sizeof(ti)` не подходит. Хотя если использовать явный `ANSI` функционал для создания всплывающей подсказки, то с `sizeof(ti)` все работает.

Comment: @Максим Глухманюк, нет, проблемы с `sizeof(ti)` быть не может, причина явно в другом. И кажется, я догадываюсь в чем. Структуры WinAPI перед заполнением нужно обнулять **всегда**. Добавьте перед заполнением команду `memset(&ti, 0, sizeof(ti));`. Ну или `::SecureZeroMemory(&ti, sizeof(ti));` чтобы уж совсем железобетонно.

Comment: @freaim, изначально я все обнулял, проблема точно не в этом.

Comment: @Максим Глухманюк, тем не менее это явная ошибка, `lpReserved` - цитата из документации: "_Must be set to NULL_". У вас работает, когда вы устанавливаете `cbSize` в версию 1 или 2, то есть когда `lpReserved` игнорируется. Как только ставите в версию 3, с ненулевым `lpReserved` работать перестает. Все в точности соответствует.

Comment: @freim, я пробую обнулять `ti`, а размер задаю как `ti.cbSize = sizeof(ti);`, но всплывающая подсказка не работает... Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @MGNeo, Кроме необнуленного `lpReserved` у вас была еще и ошибка с манифестом. Ответил в теме первого вопроса, там это обсуждение будет уместнее.